# CoreLocation not working for Adhoc Distribution on iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-location, testflight

I've been developing an app that depends on CoreLocation since the first Xcode 6 beta 1. Last week I submitted it for test on [iTunes connect/TestFlight](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224). The app works perfectly on develop devices, but when I create adhoc version, it doesn't ask for authorization.

The details:

- `Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location Warnings` didn't solve
- I set NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription on Info.plist
- CoreLocation.framework is added on `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` (but nothing changed when I remove)
- I'm using cocoapods for MBProgressHUD
- My ViewController is like: https://gist.github.com/thiagogabriel/d0120547565c91089b72
- I recently changed the Product Name to lowercase
- I started a new project from scratch and it happened the same on Adhoc for internal testers

Comment: I am seeing this as well. So far my thinking is it might be TestFlight related. I may try HockeyApp or some other Ad Hoc distribution setup.

Comment: By "works perfectly on develop devices" you mean that it works on develop builds, or even the Production build works on your devices registered on the developer program?

Comment: @MarcoPompei It works when I test using cable. The adhoc case is exactly like [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code:

```
func askForLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (locationStatus == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied) {
        let url = NSURL.URLWithString(UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    } else if (locationStatus != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    } else if (locationStatus == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("seguePlaceViewController", sender: sender)
    }
}
```

to

```
func askForLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if (locationStatus == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied) {
        let url = NSURL.URLWithString(UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url) 
    } else if (locationStatus == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("seguePlaceViewController", sender: sender)
    }
}
```

This update solves your problem.